# Why I am getting error "Malformed data passed to binarizer." while using jsQR module

Tags: node.js

`const fs = require('fs');
const jsqr = require('jsqr');
const sharp =  require('sharp');

const img = fs.readFileSync('./qr.png');

const newImg = sharp(img).resize(300, 300).toBuffer();
const qrCode = jsqr(newImg, 300, 300);

console.log(qrCode.data);`

in this code snippet of Node js i am getting error called "Malformed data passed to binarizer". why this is happening can anyone explain me ?

I am intending to decode the QR code using jsQR